# Rails how to update the page with the help of Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The object `Task` contains a `boolean` field `done`. How to `Ajax` refresh the page after the change of status? And instead `true` - `false` display value complete - incomplete?

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :tasks do
    member do
      post 'done'
    end
  end
```

**Controller:**

```
def done
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attributes(:done => params[:done])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end

  end
```

**View:**

```
....
 <td><%= task.done %></td>
 <td><%= check_box_tag 'done', task.id , task.done, :class => "task-check", remote: true %></td>
....

<script>
  $(".task-check").bind('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tasks/'+this.value+'/done',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"done": this.checked},
    });
  });

</script>
```

## Update

**edited script**

```
<script>
  $(".task-check").bind('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tasks/'+this.value+'/done',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"done": this.checked},
    }).done(function(ajax_response){
     location.reload();
    });
  });

</script>
```

**and controller**

```
def done
    @task = Task.find(params[:id]) # make sure you have this
    @task.update_attributes(:done => params["done"])

    render :json => { data: "Success", is_done: params[:done] }
  end
```

How to update page content without having to reboot ?

Comment: @toddmetheny I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
def done
  @task = Task.find(params[:id]) # make sure you have this 
  @task.update_attributes(:done => params["done"])

  render :json => { data: "Success", is_done: params[:done] }
end
```

View:

```
 ....
 <td><%= task.done %></td>
 <td><%= check_box_tag 'done', task.id , task.done, :class => "task-check" %></td>
 ....

 <script>
  $(".task-check").on('change', function(e){
    // removed remote-true. you can preventDefault if you need to but doubt page tries to refresh from a checkbox getting checked. e.preventDefault() if you need it
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/tasks/done',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {done: $('.task-check').val()},
    }).done(function(ajax_response){
      // update whatever you want after it completes 
    });
   });

 </script>
```

Didn't test this but I write these all the time. Let me know if it doesn't work post the payload and I'll figure out what's missing.

If you just want to update the value from 'incomplete' to 'complete', you can simply target the element that's called incomplete. if it has a class of, say, 'task-status' you can target that element and update in the .done part of the function. For instance:

```
$('.task-status').text('Complete')
```

should replace what previously said incomplete. If it's a text input you might use .val() instead. If it's just text on the page .text() should work.

Comment: If script `url: '/tasks/done'`, `Routing Error: No route matches [POST] "/tasks`. If you replace  `url:: '/tasks/'+this.value+'/done'` - It works. How to update without rebooting page?

Comment: How to refresh the page without rebooting after the update values?

Comment: you don't refresh--you just update the DOM. the answer is there. whatever data you want to change / update can be updated without a refresh via jquery.